# Run function from variable

Tags: php

Could I run a function from a variable? Say I had `$funcVar = somefunction`, would I be able to run it like this; `$funcVar()`? Or would I have to have the variable set to; `$funcVar = somefunction()`, and just have this; `$funcVar` in my code somewhere?

Comment: Why don't you just try? You'll find the answer faster this way.

Comment: http://3v4l.org/PRXQd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can store the name of a function in an variable and then call the function using variable

**Example:**

```
function example(){
 // Your Code
}
$fun="example";
//Calling function
$fun();
```

*Note:* This is not something like function `example()` is *refereed/stored* in variable `$fun` its just because of the value of variable is same as function name ,any changes in value of variable and you wont be able to call the function using this variable.

**Update:**
Using Class Example:

```
class test{
    static function demo(){
        echo "hai\n";
    }
}
$a="demo";
test::$a();
$ob=new test();
$ob->$a();
```

Comment: So, say that function was in a class, then how would it work. I tried to do the same thing but like `$fun = "$class->example()"; $fun;`. That throws errors, though.

Comment: Updated My answer Hope it helps.

Comment: And you cannot store class name or object name inside an variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a function to a variable. E.g, assume you have the function myFunc:

```
function myFunc() {
   echo "hello, world!";
}
```

It can be assigned to a variable

```
$var = "myFunc";
```

And then called:

```
$var();
```